# Prove that a function in one to one and onto.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function $f(x) = 2\lfloor x\rfloor - x$ where $x \in \Bbb{R}.$

So my current idea using $x = n + r$. So $2\, \mbox{floor}(x) - x = 2n-(n+r) = n-r$. And then would I somehow use the definition of one to one, where $f(a) = f(b)$ then $a = b$ to show that it is one to one?

As for onto I'm not sure how to prove it at all?

Comment: Rational?​​​​​​

Comment: @user2345215 Yes the function has the domain as a rational numbers.

Comment: So the shouldn't it be $f:\Bbb{Q} \to \Bbb{Q}$?

Comment: Sorry I was confused the question should be Real to Real (ℝ --> ℝ)

Answer (score 1):

For one to one: Suppose $f(x) = f(y)$.

So, $2floor(x) - x = 2floor(y) - y$ thus $y - x = 2floor(x)  - 2floor(y)$. What does this tell you about $x-y$? Once you see that, it'll become  clear why $x= y$.

For onto: You noticed that $f(n+r) = n - r$. So, pick a $y$. Can you write as a $n - r$? Hint: $n - r = (n+1) + (1-r)$

Comment: for one to one. I see that x =y because 2floor(x) - 2floor(y) is 2x -2y (because floor(x) = floor (n + r) 0<= r < 1, therefore r is zero. Since x = y we have proved it is one to one!

Comment: how does n -r = (n+1) + (1- r)

Comment: Whoops. What I want to say is, $n+r = (n+1) - (1-r)$. Signs in the wrong order ^^;;

Comment: Right that makes more sense. when you say choose a y, can that be any number, say 5 and I just have to prove that it can be created by (n+1)-(1-r)? I'm not getting how this proves f(y) = x?

Comment: We want to say given $y$, there is an $x$ such that $f(x) = y$. If $x = n +r $, then $f(x) = n - r$. So, find $n$ and $r$ such that $y = n - r$, and you're done. To do this, we know that we can write $y$ as $n' + r'$ for some $n',r'$. Now, use what I said earlier to figure our what should your $n$ and $r$ be in terms of $n'$ and $r'$.

Answer (score 0):

For onto I always remember this definition:

$f: A\mapsto B\\
\forall y \in B\\ \exists x\in A$

such that

$f(x)=y$.

So start with your codomain. Suppose $y$ is an arbitrary $\in \mathbb{R}$. Does there exist $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=y$? That is what you need to prove for surjectivity. Finding the correct $x$ st $f(x)=y$ is the challenge usually.